# Legacy ASP classic app, needs consistent table widths, dynamic textarea columns?

Tags: html, css

We have a classic ASP app, and all of the data is rendered using Tables (yes, we're working on changing it over to DIVs, but we're a ways away from that yet).  We've set a standard table width, and usually this works fine, but there are elements that can by sized at the user's discretion.

The issue is when it comes to textareas, the col attribute can force the table to be larger than the standard.  The question is, is there a way to define the textarea cols to be a "no larger than" value rather than a "must be" value?

```
<textarea cols="85">
```

[Fiddle of this in action](https://jsfiddle.net/714Ljhog/)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a23ky2x2/

Use the CSS rule:

```
table textarea { width: 100%; }
```

You can then set the `cols` attribute to be lower, and the textarea will span the inside of the table cell automagically. I know it's not exactly what you asked, but it looked like you wanted the textbox to fill the cell and not stretch it out and this CSS will do exactly that.